# Reason behind ZK error "The resource you request is no longer available"

Tags: java, zk

I've come across people mentioning about the error message -

> The resource you request is no longer available: /view/Index.zul
>   (z_t6w). This is normally caused by timeout, or opening too many Web
>   pages. You have to reload the page and try again.

And found a couple of script modifications to be made as the fix.

Now my situation is different. Our product uses ZK-5.0.8 (upgrading is currently not an option) and we cannot modify the jar as it is available on the fly and not locally.

I'm more concerned about **what could be the reason behind this error message to come up!** Is there any other way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There could be plenty of reason for this bug,as you are using very old version of Zk framework its hard for me to help you beyond it .

1 Did you declared `session-timeout` in **zk.xml** file ? If not declare it and after session timeout show some page with decent message

```
<sessionconfig>
    <sessiontimeout>20</session-timeout>
</sessionconfig>
```

You can also setup timeout url

```
    <device-config>
        <device-type>ajax</device-type>
        <timeout-uri>/timeout.zul</timeout-uri>
        <!-- An empty URL can cause the browser to reload the same URL -->
    </device-config>
```

2. Have you declared `max-desktops-per-session` in **zk.xml** ?

> It specifies the maximal allowed number of desktops per session. A
>   desktop represents a HTML page for a browser. In other words, this
>   number controls the number of concurrent browser windows allowed per
>   session.
>
> A negative number means no limitation at all.
>
> Note: If you use org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.GlobalDesktopCacheProvider, then
>   you have to make this number much larger since it means the maximal
>   allowed number of deskoper per system.

3. There could be more reason of this issue like it could be third party application specific see this [ZK Forum question](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/92340/the-resource-you-request-is-no-longer-available/)